# OpenRefine: How to create a unique row for each input in a column ( dilneated by comma)

Tags: duplicates, data-cleaning, openrefine

I have a bunch of product data to clean prior to entry into a database that looks like this:

| COL A | COL B | COL C... "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option 1 | A, B, C, D | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 2 | C, D, F | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 3 | D, J, Z | Option 3 attribute |

And I'd like for it to look like this with a unique row for every unique product option:

| COL A | COL B | COL C... "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option 1 | A | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | B | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | C | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | D | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 2 | C | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 | D | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 | F | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 3 | D | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 | J | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 | Z | Option 3 attribute |

I understand how I could do this with a python script, but I am already using OpenRefine, and I am hoping not to involve a whole new process to my data flow.

Is there an easy way to do this in OpenRefine? I am having a hard time finding a method or extensions for something like this.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

@magdmartin
How can you fill down blank cells using delineated values from the first cell?

| COL A | COL B | COL C... "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option 1 | A,B,C,D | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 |  | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 |  | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 |  | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 2 | C,D,F | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 |  | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 |  | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 3 | D,J,Z | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 |  | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 |  | Option 3 attribute |

Turned into

| COL A | COL B | COL C... "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option 1 | A | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | B | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | C | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | D | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 2 | C | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 | D | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 | F | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 3 | D | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 | J | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 | Z | Option 3 attribute |

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recorded a video here walking through each options describe below here: https://youtu.be/3194zXoJtqI

For this project, you will need to use two OpenRefine functions

- [Split multi-valued cells](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#split-multi-valued-cells) on `COL B` to create one new line for each value separated by comma
- [Fill down and blank down](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#fill-down-and-blank-down) to fill down the value in the other column from the menu.

If you have a lot of columns you can use the `All > Transform` to speed up the process with the following expression `row.record.cells[columnName].value[0]`. The trick here is to fill down `Col A` **last** so we can keep the [record mode](https://kb.refinepro.com/2012/03/difference-between-record-and-row.html) when filling down other column (see screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @magdmartin this is immensely useful! I have a follow up question as well. How can you fill down blank cells using delineated values from the first cell in a column?
I'm adding an edit above using a similarly formatted example.

Comment: Can you post it as a separate question so others can answer it (and it will be more visible)?

Comment: Posted! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877720/openrefine-how-to-fill-down-blank-cells-using-delineated-values-from-the-first

Comment: Does it matter if you're in ROWS or RECORDS view for this process?

Comment: @Jerry yes the records mode is important when you fill down