# OpenRefine: How to fill down blank cells using delineated values from the first cell?

Tags: excel, bigdata, data-cleaning, openrefine

How can you fill down blank cells using delineated values from the first cell?

| COL A | COL B | COL C... "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option 1 | A,B,C,D | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 |  | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 |  | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 |  | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 2 | C,D,F | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 |  | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 |  | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 3 | D,J,Z | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 |  | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 |  | Option 3 attribute |

Turned into

| COL A | COL B | COL C... "N" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Option 1 | A | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | B | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | C | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 1 | D | Option 1 attribute |
| Option 2 | C | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 | D | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 2 | F | Option 2 attribute |
| Option 3 | D | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 | J | Option 3 attribute |
| Option 3 | Z | Option 3 attribute |

How could you do this with multiple columns at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could delete all rows with empty `COL B`, then use `Edit Cells` > `split multi-valued cells…` on `COL B` and use `All` > `Edit columns` > `Fill down` to fill the now empty rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

- First, blank down the first column so that it creates a records structure (`Edit cells` -> `Blank down`). Make sure you do this in rows mode.
- Second, use the `Edit cells` -> `Split multi-valued cells` to spread your cell values inside the record structure
- Optionally, you can fill down (`Edit cells` -> `Fill down`) your first column again (to remove the records structure).